# DateTime.TryParseExact() not recognizing the PM designator, AM working as expected

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a program to read log files, converting timestamps along the way. Currently, I am using `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to quickly analyze timestamps, ensuring things are correct. The issue I am running into is only AM designators are being recognized, PM are working without issue. I have isolated the issue in the below snippet:

```
string format = "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt";

string teststringPM = "1/21/2019 3:25:32 PM";
string teststringAM = "1/21/2019 3:25:32 AM";

DateTime placeholderPM;
DateTime placeholderAM;

DateTime.TryParseExact(teststringPM, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out placeholderPM);
DateTime.TryParseExact(teststringAM, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out placeholderAM);

Console.WriteLine("placeholderPM:");
Console.WriteLine(placeholderPM.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("placeholderAM:");
Console.WriteLine(placeholderAM.ToString());
```

The output from this looks like:

```
placeholderPM:
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

placeholderAM:
1/21/2019 3:25:32 AM
```

We can see that the placeholderPM is the default new datetime value. I have tried changing the IFormatProvider to en-US, without any change in behavior.

Any insight greatly appreciated!

Comment: Side note: logs that don't use ISO8601 (with time zone or UTC) for timestamps are generally useless... you really don't need to parse them and can safely throw them away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you might be using the 'H' identifier instead of 'h'. This is an expected behavior as a upper case 'H' is used for 24 hour time. Using a lower case 'h' should resolve this issue.

For example, the format would become:

```
string format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
```

[This goes into more detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#hSpecifier)